# angular2-jwt - Calling function 'provideAuth', function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

I'm using **angular2-jwt** plugin for Authentication in my angular2/4 app. but after setting up the environment i can use it for once. after rebuilding the project the below error shows up.

error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'provideAuth', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/user/projects/project/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/user/projects/project/src/app/app.module.ts

my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
   HttpModule,
   BrowserModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
   TabsModule.forRoot(),
   ChartsModule,
   LaddaModule,
   FormsModule,
   ToasterModule
],
declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   LoginComponent,
   FullLayoutComponent,
   AsideToggleDirective,
   DashboardMenuComponent,
],
providers: [
  {
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  // useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
  // deps: [Http, RequestOptions],
  useClass: HashLocationStrategy,
  },
  AuthenticationService,
  AuthGuard,
  Auth,
  AuthHttp,
  provideAuth({
     headerName: 'Authorization',
     headerPrefix: 'bearer',
     tokenName: 'token',
     // tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('token')),
     globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
     noJwtError: true
})
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

after getting this error i export the function like this:

```
export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http, options);
}
```

and **imported** in providers but the error will be:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AuthHttp!

after adding **AuthHttp** in providers the error will be:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AuthConfig!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide as

```
    providers: [
     AuthHttp,
     {
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
        deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
     }
   ]


   export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
       return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
          headerName: 'Authorization',
          headerPrefix: 'bearer',
          tokenName: 'token',
          // tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('token')),
          globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
          noJwtError: true
      }), http, options);
    }
```

Comment: if i change my code like this, the error will be **Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthConfig: (?).**

Comment: Configuration params are passed to `AuthConfig` function?